# How to configure Prometheus outside of Kubernetes - Elastic Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, amazon-iam, kubectl, amazon-eks

I need help configuring Prometheus outside of EKS Cluster?

**What I have done:**

1. Created an EKS Cluster,
2. Installed Prometheus in EC2 outside of EKS.
3. Added `IAM Role` with EKS full access to EC2. (Able to access the cluster from aws-cli)
4. Configured `aws-auth` configmap to include the above IAM role, can get the `/healthz` of EKS with IAM Role's token attached to the EC2 using
   `curl  -k https://kubeapi-url/healthz --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"`

**Issue:**
Token has an expiration time of 15mins by default(I don't need to change this for security reasons). So, I can not use this Token directly inside the `prometheus.yml` config.

**What do I need:**

1. How can I access EKS without Token and Kubectl?
2. How to configure `prometheus.yml` to make it automatically obtain
   Token just like the Kubeconfig file of EKS does with

```
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - ap-south-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - eks-cluster-name
      command: aws
```

3. Or is there any other way to configure Prometheus without the kubernetes token?

(Prometheus config with my requirement for EKS is Greatly appreciated.)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the 2nd question:

Since you have an automatically renewed Kubeconfig file, in `prometheus.yml` configuration file you could use it directly.

```yaml
# Optional path to a kubeconfig file.
# Note that api_server and kube_config are mutually exclusive.
[ kubeconfig_file: <filename> ]
```

Not sure this is useful for your case.

Comment: Let me check...

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer, but you can use [Prometheus federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/.).

1. Setup Prometheus inside the cluster, with default config, and it automatically scrapes everything. Not much configuration required.
2. Setup the prometheus on EC2 Box and use federation config as [mentioned here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/.)

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'federate'
    scrape_interval: 15s

    honor_labels: true
    metrics_path: '/federate'

    params:
      'match[]':
        - '{job="prometheus"}'
        - '{__name__=~"job:.*"}'

    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - '<k8s-prometheus-endpoint>'
        - '<someother-prometheus-endpoint>'
```

There won't be any token used, so comparatively much more secure. All using k8s serviceaccount and federation. Consumes lot more resources but still we get sort-of HA aswell.

For optimisation: You can reduced the data in k8s prometheus for 1-2 day(depends) and have data for longer duration in your EC2 prometheus.